# Multidimensional array showing duplicate values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding values to a multidimensional array using loops

```
var leg_array = {};
var enc_array = [];

for (var c = 0; c < result.routes[0].legs.length; c++) {
    leg_array[c] = {};

    for (var b = 0; b < result.routes[0].legs[c].steps.length; b++) {
        //var lat_lngs = result.routes[0].legs[c].steps[b].encoded_lat_lngs;  //encoded polyline representation
        var start_location_A = result.routes[0].legs[c].steps[b].start_location.A;
        var start_location_F = result.routes[0].legs[c].steps[b].start_location.F;

        var end_location_A = result.routes[0].legs[c].steps[b].end_location.A;
        var end_location_F = result.routes[0].legs[c].steps[b].end_location.F;



        enc_array[b] = start_location_A + "," + start_location_F + ":" + end_location_A + "," + end_location_F;
        leg_array[c] = enc_array;

    }
}

console.log(leg_array);
```

When i check the console log, the arrays in the first level of the multi dimensional array are identical.

How can i solve this?   Values of `enc_array` are duplicate in every `leg_array`
e.g.  `leg_array[0] = enc_array, leg_array[1] = enc_array`

`enc_array` is the same when the values should be different.

Comment: Why should the values be different? You're doing `leg_array[c] = enc_array;`

Comment: Aside from `leg_array` being an object you're using as a map instead of an array, I'm inclined to think the problem will have something to do with that you're setting the entire `enc_array` each time as a property of `leg_array`. Could you provide some sample data for `result.routes`? It's a bit tough to test this code without the input.

Comment: @KingMob  - the values of `enc_array` should be different because of the first for loop.

Comment: @Shilly result.routes is from google maps api.  The sample data is huge.  Instead of a map how would i do a multidimensional array in jquery?

Comment: `leg_array` contains many references to the same `enc_array`. Maybe write some self-contained code that clearly illustrates your problem.

Comment: @KingMob , how do i add another array to `leg_array[c]`  This should prevent duplicate and i can remove `enc_array`.

Comment: Just add it. `leg_array[c] = [];` Perhaps you should reformulate your question.

Comment: You can push arrays into other arrays, but yes, it's getting a bit complicated what your result should be.

Comment: i tried this and nothing showing in console log `leg_array[c].push(start_location_A+","+start_location_F+":"+end_location_A+","+end_location_F);`

Comment: your leg_array has to be an array instead of an object to be able to use `push`. Can you give a short example which structure your result has to be? I have a feeling this could just be a complicated `array.map`.

Comment: Thannks for the help, its solved now.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the same array multiple times. If you want to create different arrays for each leg_array[c] value, use the [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method instead:

`leg_array[c] = enc_array.slice()`

This will create a new copy of enc_array (in it's current form) to store in leg_array[c].

Of course, if you do that in the current location, it will set that same value multiple times (because it's inside the loop). Moving it to be inside the outer for loop will probably get the result you want.